# Pyspark - Get column names that have a certain date format and convert them

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe where first I want to check which columns have the following format: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" ex: (2024-01-04T12:39:53Z)`

The columns I want to check are all strings, so I can filter only the columns that are strings.

I tried this code but it's not working:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "2024-01-04T12:39:53Z", "other_value", "test1"),
    (2, "2023-02-15T09:24:36Z", "2024-01-04T12:39:53Z", "test2"),
], ["id", "column1", "column2", "column3"])

target_format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"

string_columns = [column for column in df.columns if df.schema[column].dataType == "string"]

for column in string_columns:
    try:
        df = df.withColumn(column, to_timestamp(col(column), target_format).cast(TimestampType()))
    except:
        pass

print("Columns with values in the specified format:")
print(string_columns)
```

The expected result should be column1 and column2.

My goal after is to obtain the columns that have this format dynamically and then convert them to this format dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss `(example 2024-01-04T12:39:53Z to 04/01/2024 12:39:53)`

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Filtering based on column type will apply for all columns which are string. and converting to expected format will not be timestamp type it will be still in string itself.

Comment: Hi @JayashankarGS I've already obtained the result I wanted. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what I intended with this solution/code:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "2024-01-04T12:39:53Z", "other_value", "test1"),
    (2, "2023-02-15T09:24:36Z", "2024-01-04T12:39:53Z", "test2"),
    (3, "2023-09-22T09:05:10.9918535Z", "2023-01-16T09:09:09.606Z", "test3"),
], ["id", "column1", "column2", "column3"])

target_formats = ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"]
new_format = "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss"

string_columns = [column for column in df.columns if df.schema[column].dataType.typeName() == "string"]

for column in string_columns:
    conversion_expr = col(column)
    for target_format in target_formats:
        conversion_expr = when(
            to_timestamp(from_utc_timestamp(col(column), "UTC"), target_format).isNotNull(),
            date_format(to_timestamp(from_utc_timestamp(col(column), "UTC"), target_format), new_format)
        ).otherwise(conversion_expr)
    df = df.withColumn(column, conversion_expr)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**